# Getting this error even though data confirmed to exist on the prior line! hat am I missing? TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the scenario..
I'm querying a database and populating an array full of objects. In this case the objects are articles.
I am creating a filter based on categories. The goal is to run the array of objects through a filter that checks for a category match.
Line 45-48 is attempting to create that filter.
I declare a variable, set it equal to the result returned by the filter method. However, when the includes method executes I get an error telling me "Cannot read property includes of undefined".
Clearly as we can see in the console my array of objects is being printed from the line directly before the filter and the object clearly contains a categories field containing an array.
What the hell am I not getting?
[Proof data is logging out from the console.log in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbTN7.png)

```
function RenderFilteredList(props) {
console.log(props.allPosts);
let filteredPosts = props.allPosts.filter((post, index) =>
  post.categories.includes(props.category)
);

return (
  <div className="posts-grid">
    {filteredPosts &&
      filteredPosts.map((post, index) => (
        <div className="grid-post-card" key={post.slug.current}>
          <Link to={"/" + post.slug.current}>
            <img
              className="grid-image"
              src={urlFor(post.featuredImage).width().url()}
              alt=""
            />
            <p className="grid-post-title">{post.title}</p>
            <p className="grid-post-author">
              {post.name + " - " + post.date}
            </p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: `allPosts` is not the same thing as `props.addPosts`...

Comment: allPosts is the state. I have tried this 1 million ways, passing it through props and not through props. Every time I still get this issue. I just removed the props reference from everything inside the render function and still get the error. Also just confirmed logging props.allPosts results in the same output in console.

Comment: It fails on the last element  in the allPosts array - It looks like it doesn't have "categories" member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot of the console, there's no `categories` shown for the fourth item in `allPosts`.

Since the error could occur if **any** item in `allPosts` doesn't have `categories`, have you confirmed whether it's present in all items?

You might need to change your `filter` function to check for the existence of the `categories` field and exclude items that don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

you have i typo, you are logging `allPosts` but you are accessing props.allPosts

```js
let filteredPosts = allPosts.filter((post, index) =>
  post.categories.includes(props.category)
);
```

Comment: I corrected the code to log props.allPosts to be consistent and am getting the same output on console and same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fourth item in the props.allPosts might not contain a categories array. Can you check that every post in allPosts has a categories array?

Comment: Yes this was the culprit. 
Thank you for catching it. 
I'm super grateful!